# Pagination and alphabatic filter issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use pagination and an alphabetic filter in jQuery. It is working fine but I want to add one more link (all) and when user click on that link it will show all the data.

JS Code here:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
        $('ul.items li').hide().filter('.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1)).show();
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    var itemsNumber = 10;
    var min = 0;
    var max = itemsNumber;

    function pagination(action) {
        var totalItems = $("#item-wrapper").find("li").length;
        if (max < totalItems) { //Stop action if max reaches more than total items 
            if (action == "next") {
                min = min + itemsNumber;
                max = max + itemsNumber;
            }
        }

        if (min > 0) { //Stop action if min reaches less than 0
            if (action == "prev") {
                min = min - itemsNumber;
                max = max - itemsNumber;
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        $("#item-wrapper").find("li").hide();
        $("#item-wrapper").find("li").slice(min, max).show();

        if (action == "next"){
         if (max < totalItems)
             {
               $("#prev").removeClass("previous_link_gray");
               $("#prev").addClass("previous_link");
             }
             else
             {
                $("#next").removeClass("next_link");
                $("#next").addClass("next_link_gray");
             }
        }

        if (action == "prev"){
                 if (min>0)
                     {
                       $("#next").removeClass("next_link_gray");
                       $("#next").addClass("next_link");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                       $("#prev").removeClass("previous_link");
                       $("#prev").addClass("previous_link_gray");
                     }
                }
                var mymax = max;
                if(parseInt(max) > parseInt(totalItems)) {
                    mymax = totalItems;
                }

                var pagelbl = (parseInt(min) + 1) + ' to ' + mymax + ' of ' + totalItems;
                $("#spnpage").html(pagelbl);
            }

    pagination();

    //Next
    $("#next").click(function () {
        action = "next";
        pagination(action);

    })

    //Previous
    $("#prev").click(function () {
        action = "prev";
        pagination(action);
    })
});   //]]>  

function getSelected(Alphabet)  {
    $(".filter").find('a').removeClass('Selected');
    $("#" + Alphabet).addClass('Selected');
    $("#prev").removeClass("previous_link_gray");
    $("#next").removeClass("next_link_gray");
    $("#prev").addClass("previous_link");
    $("#next").addClass("next_link");
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#category-a11" id="all" onclick="getSelected('All')" class="Selected">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#category-A" id="A" onclick="getSelected('A')">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#category-B" id="B" onclick="getSelected('B')">B</a></li>
```

Comment: You should create jsfiddle, because in your code you'll accomplish many interactions and your HTML contains only links for performing that interactions and not exact structure

Comment: Moreover you have no line in your code filtering data alphabetically. But if it works when you filter on a single letter, you just have to select all data in your list instead of the data filtered by the first letter to make your code work, haven't you?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide more of your html, but it seems like all you need to do is `show()` every list item in your `#item-wrapper` eg.

```
$("#item-wrapper").find("li").show();

// A slightly more process efficient way of selecting would be
$("#item-wrapper li").show();
```

So your `getSelected` function would become:

```
function getSelected(Alphabet){
    if(Alphabet == "all"){
        // Hide prev/next btns as they wont make sense to user
        $("#prev, #next").hide();
        // Show the items
        $("#item-wrapper li").show();
    }else{
        $(".filter").find('a').removeClass('Selected');
        $("#" + Alphabet).addClass('Selected');
        $("#prev").show().removeClass("previous_link_gray");
        $("#next").show().removeClass("next_link_gray");
        $("#prev").addClass("previous_link");
        $("#next").addClass("next_link");
    }
}
```

Does that make sense with your current markup?